# MVC EditorFor with Dropdownlist and Textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm still new to MVC, I don't quite get how `EditorFor` works in MVC 5.

I'm building a project based on an existing database, so it makes sense to use the Database First approach for the EF. I have no problem creating the model and the initial template, but there is one column in my database looks like this:

```
Plant ID    Leaf Color
1           Green
2           Yellow
3           Green
4           Red
5           Green
6           Purple
```

Since Green and Yellow are the more common colors for a plant's leaves,

1. First part of the question: I want to create a DropDownList with the options: `Green, Yellow and Other`. (i.e. so if the color is Red, it should point to "other" in the DropDownList)
2. Second Part of the question: Once that happen, or when the "other" was selected, a new `TextBox` will appear for the user to enter the color manually.

Because of this, it also messes up the Model binding and the MVC Validation.

In MVC 5, when creating a Template using `MVC Controller with read/write actions and views, using Entity Framework`, the `EditorFor` will automatically create a `TextBox` for this field. There is no problem with the `Index.cshtml` and `Delete.cshtml` since they do not involve the `EditorFor`. However, the problem occurs in `Edit.cshtml` and `Create.cshtml`.

How am I going to achieve what I need?

Additional Info: I'm qutie familiar with jQuery, when doing ASP.NET WebForm, I know how to use jQuery to hide/show the Textbox, but I just don't seem to understand how to apply this to EditorFor and LabelFor

Comment: Create a view model with separate properties for the dropdown and textbox

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery to copy the value from two visible controls (which are ignored on postback) to an invisible one (which is used as colour on postback). Something like this; with jquery on the change events to keep the controls synchronised.

```
<div class="visible-controls">
<select>
    <option>select</option>
    <option>Green</option>
    <option>Yellow</option>
    <option>Other</option>
</select>
<input type="text" placeholder="other" />
</div>
<div class="invisible-controls">
<input type="text" name="colour" />
</div>
```

I guess the main point is that Editorfor won't produce something like this by default. You will have to get closer to the raw html for complex controls and not use HtmlHelper

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

The html goes within your html page just under your ViewBag

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
<p>
   Colour: @Html.DropDownList("Colour", "Select")

   @Html.TextBox


</p>
}
```

> Create a new method within your controller and add this in. It
>   creates a new dropdown list with the three items you want

```
 public ActionResult Index(string Colour)
        {
           //Create a Dropdown list
            var SearchOptionList = new List<string>();
            SearchOptionList.Add("Green");
            SearchOptionList.Add("Yellow");
            SearchOptionList.Add("Other");

 var mylist = from m in "your database table name goes in here" select m;

//Clears dropdown list
 ModelState.Remove("Colour")

return View(mylist.ToList());

}
```

You'd have better experience than me with JQuery and you said you know to make the textbox appear so you should just adapt that in.